# Sum of the following ncr series in O(1) time complexity

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, combinatorics

There are multiple queries of the form

> Q(n,m) = (nC1*mC1) + (nC2*mC2) + (nC3*mC3) ... (nCk*mCk) where
>   k=min(n,m)

How to find the value of **Q(n,m) in O(1)** time complexity.

I tried pre-computing ncr[N][N] matrix and dp[N][N][N] where `dp[n][m][min(n,m)] = Q(n,m).`

This pre-computation takes O(N^3) time and queries can be answered in O(1) time now. But I'm looking for an approach in which pre-computation shouldn't take more O(N^2) time.

Comment: dp[n][m][min(n,m)] is equivalent to dp[n][m], because given n and m, there is only 1 min(n, m)

Comment: @juvian but how would you calculate dp[n][m] in that case! Previously I was using the recurrence dp[m][n][k]=dp[m][n][k-1]+(ncr[m][k]*ncr[n][k]) that accurately gave the result.

Comment: @juvian, you mean `dp[n][m] = dp[m][n]` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution for starting from C(n,0)*C(m,0) seems pretty simple

```
Q0(n,m) = C(n+m, m)
```

So for your formulation just subtract 1

```
Q(n,m) = C(n+m, m) - 1
```

Example: n=9, m=5

Dot product of 9-th and 5-th rows of Pascal's triangle is

```
1   9     36    84    126   126  84  36  9  1
1   5     10    10    5     1
1 + 45 +  360 + 840 + 630 + 126                = 2002    = C(14,5)
```

It might be proved with math induction starting from Q(n,1) but expressions are rather long.

*I have discovered a truly marvelous demonstration of this proposition that this margin is too narrow to contain  © Fermat ;)*